# Charge density of two parallel planes

Tags: electrostatics

Given are two parallel conducting planes with a potential $V(x)$ given by $V(x)=\alpha x +\beta$ where $x=0$ is chosen to be be at one of the planes. Calculate the charge density on one of the planes.

The solutions manual does this by using the fact that $\vec E =-\nabla V$ combined with a Gaussian pillbox, which results in $\rho=\pm b\epsilon_0$

But, when we resort to Poisson, which reads that $\nabla^2 V=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}$. Using this implies that $\rho=0$, but this contradicts the answer we got with Gauss.

Where does it go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking for the **surface** charge density which is $\pm \alpha \epsilon_0$. The **volume** charge density is indeed zero, as you have found. I think the fact that your book is using $\rho$, commonly used for volume charge density, as the symbol for surface charge density (the symbol for which is $\sigma$) is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The charge density must be computed on ONE of the plates. You have to use the integral form of the Gauss law:

$- \int_V \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} dV = \int_A \vec{E}d \vec{A}$.

Here, $A$ is the surface of one plate and $\vec{E}$ is constant on this plate. Hence, you get

$- \int_V \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} dV = \alpha A = - \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$.

Now you can determine the total charge $Q$ and you can assume that the charge density (electrons per volume) is given by

$\rho = \frac{Q}{V}$.

For the other plate, the surface normal vector points to opposite direction; therefore you get an opposite sign in your solution.